# Using Index of Multiple Deprivation (IMD) Scores in a Linear Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, ordinal-data

The UK Government publishes deprivation scores for geographic areas. Often these scores are converted into ranks and then into quantiles to see if groups of people are more or less deprived than one would expect.

The IMD score is ordinal, Area A may be more deprived than Area B, but we cannot say by how much.

Is it valid to use IMD *Rank* as an independent variable in a simple or multiple linear regression?

More information on IMD here: [English Indices of Deprivation 2010](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/6222/1871538.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: you're not invalidating any assumption of the linear model. Of course there's no guarantee your model will be much use - there never is. I'd be inclined to try the raw deprivation scores first if they were available.

Comment: Thanks @Scortchi, raw scores are available to me, in fact I even have the domain scores that are combined to make up the overall IMD score so I'm tempted to split them out and add as separate variables.